# Anatomy of HTML by big name companies

Tags: html

Are there any blogs or other postings that detail the anatomy of HTML code served by a very big name commercial operation like say Google, Apple, Twitter, Facebook, etc?

I'm just asking for a close piece by piece guide to understanding the structure and design of an HTML page written by an industry leader for the purpose of learning by example. I am especially interested in this kind of guide for a "static" page rather than part of an interactive web app.

Note: I am perfectly well versed in HTML and web dev, as are most people on this SE, so when answering please assume that we are already familiar with plenty of general tutorials and style guides but are looking (maybe out of curiosity) for analysis of an exemplary HTML page made by a top end company.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the items listed here might be of help to you:  [How do you determine what technology a website is built on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396739/how-do-you-determine-what-technology-a-website-is-built-on)

For example [built with](http://builtwith.com/) lists the javascript libraries, HTML doctypes, CMS Systems, security tags, and server side technologies that the website uses.  Here is their info for the sites you requested:

- [Google](http://builtwith.com/google.com)
- [Apple](http://builtwith.com/apple.com)
- [Twitter](http://builtwith.com/twitter.com)
- [Facebook](http://builtwith.com/facebook.com)